# Number rows by a specified number of occurence of values in another column and then averaging values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102),
  `Event Full` = c('a',
                   'a',
                   'a',
                   'a',
                   'a',
                   'a',
                   'b',
                   'b'),
  Scores = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
)
```

I want to number each 'unique' `Event Full`, where a unique entry is defined as every two rows of a type of value in `Event Full` (e.g. 2 'a's, 2 'b's in this case). Then, I want to average the scores for each unique event.

This is the example output:

```
solution <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101, 102, 102, 102),
  `Event Full` = c('a',
                   'a',
                   'a',
                   'b'),
  Num = c(1,1,2,3),
  Scores = c(1,2,3,4)
)
```

Does anyone know how to do this efficiently?

Thank you!

Comment: Where does *Num* come from?

Comment: Num is from the number of 'unique' Event Full, where a unique entry is defined as every two rows of a type of value in Event Full (e.g. 2 'a's, 2 'b's in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
aggregate(Scores~., cbind(data, Num = gl(nrow(data),2, nrow(data))), mean)

  Subject Event.Full Num Scores
1     101          a   1      1
2     102          a   2      2
3     102          a   3      3
4     102          b   4      4
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting a second grouping value by modulus `%%` to fulfill the "*every two rows*" requirement, then `summarize` to get the `mean` values.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 2

data %>% 
  mutate(Num = cumsum(row_number() %% n == 1), .by = Subject) %>% 
  summarize(Scores = mean(Scores), .by = c(Subject, 'Event Full', Num))
  Subject Event Full Num Scores
1     101          a   1      1
2     102          a   1      2
3     102          a   2      3
4     102          b   3      4
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Wildberg! How should I modify this code if I want it to be every 8 rows?

Comment: @jo_ Try the edit, where you change `n <- 2` to `n <- 8`.